# xml transform in data weave 2.0

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule-component, mule4

In my case, I have an XML Request and Expected response payload. But I don't know to transform using Dataweave 2.0

Input XMl :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DTOApplication id="Application-1660258480-1493174910" ApplicationNumber="AP-00006354" Version="3.10">
    <QuestionReplies id="QuestionReplies-1553101003-1178947042">
        <QuestionReply id="QuestionReply-859195405-1832325773" Name="1000" Value="NO" VisibleInd="Yes"/>
        <QuestionReply id="QuestionReply-1656171536-493197768" Name="1000A" VisibleInd="No"/>
    </QuestionReplies>
    <DTORisk id="Risk-156119133-1700981150">
        <DTOCoverage>
            <DTOStep id="Step-Coverage-1713637162-341585712-Premium" Status="Cleared"/>
        </DTOCoverage>
    </DTORisk>
    <DTORisk id="Risk-156119133-1700981151">
        <DTOCoverage>
            <DTOStep id="Step-Coverage-1713637162-341585713-Premium" Status="Cleared"/>
        </DTOCoverage>
    </DTORisk>
    <DTOCoverage>
        <DTOStep id="Step-Coverage-1713637162-341585713-Premium" Status="Cleared"/>
    </DTOCoverage>
    <DTOCoverage>
        <DTOStep id="Step-Coverage-1713637162-341585713-Premium" Status="Cleared"/>
    </DTOCoverage>
    <DTOCoverage>
        <DTOStep id="Step-Coverage-1713637162-341585713-Premium" Status="Cleared"/>
    </DTOCoverage>
</DTOApplication>
```

Output XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DTOApplication id="Application-1660258480-1493174910" ApplicationNumber="AP-00006354" Version="3.10">
    <QuestionReplies id="QuestionReplies-1553101003-1178947042">
        <QuestionReply id="QuestionReply-859195405-1832325773" Name="1000" Value="NO" VisibleInd="Yes"/>
        <QuestionReply id="QuestionReply-1656171536-493197768" Name="1000A" VisibleInd="No"/>
    </QuestionReplies>
    <DTORisk id="Risk-156119133-1700981150">
        <DTOCoverage>
            <DTOSteps>
                        <DTOStep Order="1" Name="Final Premium" Factor="501" Value="501"/>
                    </DTOSteps>
        </DTOCoverage>
    </DTORisk>
    <DTORisk id="Risk-156119133-1700981151">
        <DTOCoverage>
            <DTOSteps>
                        <DTOStep Order="1" Name="Final Premium" Factor="502" Value="502"/>
                    </DTOSteps>
        </DTOCoverage>
    </DTORisk>
    <DTOCoverage>
        <DTOSteps>
                <DTOStep Order="1" Name="Final Premium" Factor="503" Value="503"/>
            </DTOSteps>
    </DTOCoverage>
    <DTOCoverage>
        <DTOSteps>
                  <DTOStep Order="1" Name="Final Premium" Factor="504" Value="504"/>
            </DTOSteps>
    </DTOCoverage>
    <DTOCoverage>
        <DTOSteps>
                  <DTOStep Order="1" Name="Final Premium" Factor="505" Value="505"/>
            </DTOSteps>
    </DTOCoverage>
</DTOApplication>
```

source: https://github.com/Manikandan99/jenkins-demo-cicd/blob/master/output_xml

Note:

- Difference between the input and output payload is that the value of the DTOStep node should be updated.
- The attribute value of DTOStep is autoincremented from 500 each time.

Comment: The expected output should be included in your question, not linked.

Comment: What is the question exactly? In Stackoverflow it is expected you at least tried something. If you don't know about the topic you should try first to read the documentation, do some training, follow some tutorials, then try it, and ask if you are having an error.

Comment: Also if you need help to generate the output you should explain exactly how it is different from the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you are trying to enclose the `DTOStep` elements each into a `DTOSteps` parent element. That can be done using the [update()](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-operators#update-operator) operator. To transform each child element as needed mapObject() is useful as it also provides the index. You may need to finetune the script for other inputs.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
var keys=["DTORisk", "DTOCoverage"]
var startingValue=499
fun createOutputElement(keyName, index)=keyName match {
  case "DTOCoverage" -> { DTOCoverage: DTOSteps: DTOStep @(Order:1, Name:"Final Premiun", Factor: index + startingValue, Value: index + startingValue): null }
  case "DTORisk" -> { DTORisk: DTOCoverage: DTOSteps: DTOStep @(Order:1, Name:"Final Premiun", Factor: index + startingValue, Value: index + startingValue): null }
  else -> dw::Runtime::fail("Unexpected key")
}
---
payload update {
        case risk at .DTOApplication ->
            risk mapObject ((value, key, index) -> 
                if (keys contains key as String ) createOutputElement(key as String, index) 
                else (key):value
            )
}
```

Output:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<DTOApplication id="Application-1660258480-1493174910" ApplicationNumber="AP-00006354" Version="3.10">
  <QuestionReplies id="QuestionReplies-1553101003-1178947042">
    <QuestionReply id="QuestionReply-859195405-1832325773" Name="1000" Value="NO" VisibleInd="Yes"/>
    <QuestionReply id="QuestionReply-1656171536-493197768" Name="1000A" VisibleInd="No"/>
  </QuestionReplies>
  <DTORisk>
    <DTOCoverage>
      <DTOSteps>
        <DTOStep Order="1" Name="Final Premiun" Factor="500" Value="500"/>
      </DTOSteps>
    </DTOCoverage>
  </DTORisk>
  <DTORisk>
    <DTOCoverage>
      <DTOSteps>
        <DTOStep Order="1" Name="Final Premiun" Factor="501" Value="501"/>
      </DTOSteps>
    </DTOCoverage>
  </DTORisk>
  <DTOCoverage>
    <DTOSteps>
      <DTOStep Order="1" Name="Final Premiun" Factor="502" Value="502"/>
    </DTOSteps>
  </DTOCoverage>
  <DTOCoverage>
    <DTOSteps>
      <DTOStep Order="1" Name="Final Premiun" Factor="503" Value="503"/>
    </DTOSteps>
  </DTOCoverage>
  <DTOCoverage>
    <DTOSteps>
      <DTOStep Order="1" Name="Final Premiun" Factor="504" Value="504"/>
    </DTOSteps>
  </DTOCoverage>
</DTOApplication>
```

Comment: Yeah, the update operator is correct. But see the output xml. The DTOStep node is different and notice that the value of 500 is auto increment.

Comment: How do you expect people here to know those details? Please update your question with the detail logic for the transformation and see my comments on the question too.

Comment: Your correct aled. It's a close call. How to update the attributes values of DTOStep node?

Comment: It is somewhat more complex but doable. I'll update my answer when I have more time. Please add the expected output to the question.

Comment: Updated the script and added the output for your input.

Comment: Good Job Aled. you done a great work :)