# transform the xml payload in mule 4 using dataweave 2.0

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

In my case, I've done the XML payload transform using **Java** in Mule 3.

But in Mule 4, could we be able to transform the xml payload using **Dataweave 2.0.**

I have an XML Request and Expected response payload. But I don't know to transform using Dataweave 2.0

Input XML:
https://github.com/Manikandan99/demo/blob/master/input_xml_request

Output XML:
https://github.com/Manikandan99/demo/blob/master/output_xml

Java code for my logic:
https://github.com/Manikandan99/demo/blob/master/transform_xml.java

Note:

```
        * Difference between the input and output payload is that the value of the DTOStep node should be updated.
        * The attribute value of DTOStep is autoincremented from 500 each time.
```

Please assist me.

Comment: Please use text instead of images. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question for more details on the reason.

Comment: The question lacks researching and sharing what you tried previously. You also need to clarify the difference between the input and output, not expect people to do that. Kindly read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on how to improve your question. You already have a previous question with the same output (https://stackoverflow.com/q/70770154/721855). Are there any differences to that one? Are you having any issues creating the transformation yourself? Be more specific.

Comment: Aled, you are correct. It's a close call.Is it possible to use the same Java code in Mule 4 rather than Dataweave 2.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In generic terms there are two main ways to resolve this in Mule 4.

1. Implement the desired transformation in DataWeave 2. This is usually recommended and is the natural way in Mule 4.
2. Migrate the Mule 3 Java code. This implies removing any references to Mule Java APIs, types, class, interfaces or packages from your Java code. Mule 4 expects plain Java code with not usage of Mule internals. For example that means no references to Mule events, messages nor variables. Just put everything as parameters of the methods you are calling and use the Java module. Don't assume Mule is magically sending DOM to your code. To invoke Java code in Mule 4 read the instructions in the documentations of the Java Module.

Comment: Aled! How may I contact you?

Comment: Try stackoverflow chat.

Comment: Hi, Aled. I don't know how to send message via stack overflow chat. I'm doing a migration from Mule 3 to Mule 4. I've done the XML payload transform using an XPR file by the expression component in Mule 3.I don't know how to reuse the xpr file in Mule 4 . could you please reach out to my mail trynewthing073@gmail.com.

Comment: No idea what an XPR file is. Why don't you ask a question for migrating the expression? Please add all information in the question.